# Passing a session to a Django template via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, cookies

I'm trying to `$.load()` a Django template that uses `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`. Unfortunately, the `user` object is undefined in the template when rendered on the server *only if it's in response to an AJAX-generated HTTP request*.

my_template.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div>This should be printed</div>
{% else %}
  <div>But this is because there is no user object</div>
{% endif %}
```

my_loader.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div>This works fine because I'm logged in</div>
{% endif %}
<div id="template'></div>
<script>
  $('#template').load('/my_template.html');
</script>
```

views.py (using django-annoying's `@render_to` decorator):

```
@render_to('my_template.html')
def my_template(request):
  return {}
```

The problem, as I understand it, is that the "context" available in the rendering of my_loader.html is not made available to the server through `.load()`. I don't know whether this "context" is a session, a cookie, or something in the header, but the result is that when the server renders my_template.html from an HTTP request generated through AJAX, there is no `user` object. When I load it organically in the browser it works fine.

If it helps:

- This is on the same domain.
- I've already tried using .ajax() instead with `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }`
- I've already tried using .ajax() instead with `headers: { 'sessionid': $.cookie('sessionid') }`. The sessionid cookie did not exist (although csrftoken did, so I know I was looking in the right place).

Any idea how to make the `user` object from my_loader.html available to the server when it loads pages like my_template.html via AJAX?

Comment: Can we see the view code that renders `my_template.html`? It needs to be passed a `RequestContext` instance.

Comment: Sure, added, although it's literally as simple as can be. @render_to handles passing RequestContext (verified and used extensively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I feel bad because there's actually nothing wrong with my example code--in my attempts to distill the complex *actual code* down to an abstract level to present it to you all, I inadvertently left out a complexity that was the root cause of my problem.

Turns out WTK's and my original intuition that the cookie would be passed in the `.load()` request by default was, in fact, correct (inspecting the HTTP requests confirms).

So the real issue is that actually, I didn't have one template but two nested, and the latter one was actually a template *tag*. So the real structure was more like:

my_template.html:

```
Some stuff
{% my_template_tag %}
```

my_template_tag.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div>This should be printed</div>
{% else %}
  <div>But this is because there is no user object</div>
{% endif %}
```

tags.py

```
@register.inclusion_tag('my_template_tag.html')
def my_template_tag():
  return {}
```

... where views.py and my_loader.html are the same as presented above. In retrospect, I should've noticed that the `my_template_tag()` did not take a `request` param, which means that it wouldn't be in the RequestContext to make `user` available. Basically: template tags don't implicitly have the `request` in their contexts as templates do, and since the `user` just comes from `request.user` it is also not available.

For those who may later read this, there are two solutions:

1. Pass the `user` object manually in as a parameter to the template_tag.
2. Use `{% include %}` with the `with` keyword, if possible, as it passes the request by default.

Thanks, still, for all your help [rubber-ducking](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) this! I couldn't have figured out the real problem without you guys forcing me to go back and question my original assumptions!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you expected `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` to be evaluated on Javascript side? Well, it's not how this works. Javascript has no idea of what's on the server side, and how to parse, evaluate or bind the user template variable.

In order for `$('#template').load('/my_template.html');` to work, you have to make sure that `my_template.html` gets rendered by Django **before** it's returned.
Just create a view (in Django) to render `my_template.html`. Don't worry about the session - it should work because along with your ajax request, cookies (which identify session) are sent as well, so Django can pick the right session, and pull user object from it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but no, I know the Django template is rendered on the server side. I'm asking how to make Django aware of which user is making the .load()-generated http request. I, too, thought that I wouldn't have to worry about passing the session manually--that whatever cookie is used for loading my_loader.html would be passed through .load() all the same--but it appears I do, as it is not. I already had a view. Unfortunately Django cannot, it seems "pick the right session" without more information.

Comment: Verify if there are session cookies sent along with the request. Use firebug or chrome console for that.

Comment: Yup, turns out they were actually--which helped me figure out the real problem (I was looking in the wrong place). Thanks!

Comment: No problem, remember to mark your answer as accepted to pull this question out of unanswered bucket.

Comment: Apparently I've gotta wait two days, but I'll be sure to then.